# inner product space & linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be an inner product space and $f$ a transformation $f: V \to V$.

Prove that if $\forall x, y \in V, (x,y) = (f(x), f(y))$ than $f$ is a linear transformation.

My proof:

\begin{align}
&\langle f(\alpha v) - \alpha f(v), f(\alpha v) - \alpha f(v) \rangle \\
&=\langle f(\alpha v), f(\alpha v) \rangle - \bar{\alpha} \langle f(\alpha v), f(v) \rangle - \alpha \langle f(v), f(\alpha v) \rangle + \alpha \bar{\alpha} \langle f(v), f(v) \rangle \\
&=\langle \alpha v, \alpha v \rangle - \bar{\alpha} \langle \alpha v,v \rangle - \alpha \langle v, \alpha v \rangle + \alpha \bar{\alpha} \langle v, v \rangle \\
&=\alpha \bar{\alpha} \langle v, v \rangle - \alpha \bar{\alpha} \langle v, v \rangle - \alpha \bar{\alpha} \langle v, v \rangle + \alpha \bar{\alpha}\langle v, v \rangle \\
&= 0
\end{align}

My question is, how do I show that $\langle f(u+v)-f(u)-f(v), f(u+v)-f(u)-f(v) \rangle=0$?

Comment: $V$ is finite-dimensional?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Compute
$$<f(x+y)-f(x)-f(y),f(x+y)-f(x)-f(y)>$$
and (I suppose that the base field is $\mathbb{R}$) for $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x\in V$, compute:
$$<f(ax)-af(x), f(ax)-af(x)>$$

Comment: maybe $f(ax)$ ?

Comment: @Exodd Yes, I have corrected, thank you.

Comment: @Kelenner can you cheek my edit?

Comment: @ovedpo ovedpo I have not checked the computations, but this is the correct idea; for $f(u+v)=f(u)+f(v)$, do the same computations, and you are done.

Comment: @kelenner I have some trouble with the last one. can you help with that?

Comment: You have:
$$<f(x+y)-f(x)-f(y),f(x+y)-f(x)-f(y)>=$$

$$<f(x+y),f(x+y)>-<f(x),f(x+y)>-<f(y),f(x+y)>-<f(x+y),f(x)>+<f(x),f(x)>+<f(y),f(x)>$$

$$-<f(x+y),f(y)>+<f(x),f(y)>+<f(y),f(y)>$$
and now use your hypothesis